# How to set Shipping prices for different customers over Owebia Advanced Shipping module?

Tags: shipping-methods, customer-attribute

We are trying to set customers shipping prices individually. We try to use Owebia Advanced Shipping open source module.
I know that there is a variable `{customer.id}`, but the documentation does not mention where and how I can use it. I am also interested in filtering customer according certain attribute e. g. `{client.attribute.[some atribute name]}`.

Comment: I am trying to create this sort of rule:
`{
 "meta_colissimo": {
  "type": "meta",
  "about": "Delivery prices from 2017-10-24",
  "author": "Vincas Dundzys"
 },
 "Courier 2": {
  "label": "Test delivery",
  "description": "Courier delivery",
  "conditions": "{customer.id} ==  '1'",
  "fees": 20
 }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just received an email from module creator Antoine Lemoine. It appears that everything is much simpler, than I thought. You need to put client filtering into a condition and that will be enough to rule to work.

Here is example from Antoine:

```
{
   "id_014": {
      "label": "Customer id",
      "conditions": "{customer.id} == 14",
      "fees": 10
   }
}
```

And one more:

```
{
   "id_015": {
      "label": "Customer attribute",
      "conditions": "{customer.shipping_attribute} == 'free'",
      "fees": 0
   }
}
```

Thank you Antonie!